# Wpf textblock partial background

Tags: .net, wpf-controls

I need to set a marker on a derived (inherited) textblock that will give the user an indication whether text is Left Right or Center justified. Derived class has a property called justification which is an enum with Left Right and Centre values. So I want to change background color of the textBlock partially i.e. if it is Left Justified then 25% of background on the left is a different color. Length of the string in the text block can vary and is not static.

Putting the textblock in another element e.g. border is not an option but I am open to any other suggestions that can manipulate Textblock without changing its size to visually mark justification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could assign a LinearGradientBrush to the background and [manipulate the colors and the offsets of the gradientstops](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/355/).

Comment: +1, excellent suggestion.  Note that if you want the brush to be solid colors rather than a fade, set stops of the same color.  For example, set a stop at 0, then 0.25 of one color.  Then set 0.25 to 1.0 of another color.  You'll get two solid colors.